# How to copy large amount of files from S3 folder to another

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to move large amount of files(around 300Kb max size each file) from S3 folder to another.

I'm using AWS sdk for java, and tried to move around 1500 files.

it took too much time, and the number of files may be increase to 10,000.

for each copy of file, need to delete from the source folder as there is no method to move file.

this what i tried:

```
public void moveFiles(String fromKey, String toKey) {
    Stream<S3ObjectSummary> objectSummeriesStream = this.getObjectSummeries(fromKey);
    objectSummeriesStream.forEach(file ->
        {
            this.s3Bean.copyObject(bucketName, file.getKey(), bucketName, toKey);
            this.s3Bean.deleteObject(bucketName, file.getKey());
        });

}

private Stream<S3ObjectSummary> getObjectSummeries(String key) {

    // get the files that their prefix is "key" (can be consider as Folders).
    ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(this.bucketName)
        .withPrefix(key);
    ObjectListing outFilesList = this.s3Bean.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
    return outFilesList.getObjectSummaries()
        .stream()
        .filter(x -> !x.getKey()
            .equals(key));
}
```

Comment: Are you running this code from java application or from AWS-Lambda?

Comment: @alexey28 currently there is no planning of puting this application on Lambda.

Comment: Is this a one-off job, or will more objects be arriving in Amazon S3 that need moving? If more will come, Lambda makes sense. If it is one-off, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 mv` command.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it is not one-off job. it is daily process. Lambda isn't helping me in that case since i can't move the files to another folder before i'm processing then. and i need to process them all together,they are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java application you can try to use several threads to copy files:

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.fixed(20);

public void moveFiles(String fromKey, String toKey) {
    Stream<S3ObjectSummary> objectSummeriesStream = 
    this.getObjectSummeries(fromKey);
    objectSummeriesStream.forEach(file ->
    {
        executorService.submit(() ->
            this.s3Bean.copyObject(bucketName, file.getKey(), bucketName, toKey);
            this.s3Bean.deleteObject(bucketName, file.getKey());
        )};
    });

}
```

This should speed up the process.

An alternative might be using AWS-lambda. Once the file appear in source bucket you can, for example, put event in the SQS FIFO queue. The lambda will start single file copy by this event. If I am not mistaken in parallel you can start up to 500 instances of lambdas. Should be fast.

Comment: Thanks! i will try the first soultion. by the way, if will put it on lambda,  the trigger of the lambda can be via S3 and not SQS. the problem is that this piece of code is running after some bussiness logic that should process all the files and only than move them to another folder.

Comment: In that case you can: 1) put business logic into lambdas or 2) after business logic complete put messages with processed file names into FIFO queue and trigger lambda file copy by this message

Comment: Can you compress a group of files, transfer and then decompress?

Comment: @rossumy those files are not located on the OS. they are located in S3. in order to compress, i need to download them, give write permissions to the application. in addition, how can i decompress in S3?